# Fixing misaligned rows using Python

Tags: python, pandas

[image]I'm trying to read a csv file into a dataframe in Python but when examining the file I noticed they are many misaligned rows . Does anyone know how I can shift these rows so my Dataframe's size is consistent. 
data= pd.read_csv('MyData.csv')

Comment: Can you provide an example of a few rows of your CSV file. Open it with excel or something. Include examples of this misalignment

Comment: Can you show us an example, and the code you are using?

Comment: I've just attached a pic of the data. I have many of these misaligned rows that are messing up with the dataframe's size . code: data=pd.read_csv('MyData.csv')

Comment: This is a problem best fixed at the source. It looks like entries containing the delimeter are not being properly escaped (that line probably had 'Washington, D.C.'). Do you have any control over how the CSVs are generated? Can you print the offending line as it appears in a text editor (or better, hex dump)?

Comment: It seems like it added an additional column in that row. I am quite sure it is still aligned at Washington DC. However, an NA appears and seems to have shifted the 4 numbers by 1 cell to the right. What are these values?

Answer (score 1):

What is your seperator in the csv- a comma? It would help if you could open the raw csv file in a text editor and post the result here. You could then check if this seperator can appear in the input data. You then have two options: Change the seperator (if possible) or create a small python script/ manually replace all cases in which this can happen.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I opened the file in Sublime and fixed the commas and all the rows all aligned :)

Comment: If you feel like this answered your question you can mark the answer as correct.